# replacing dropdown lookup with related user field

Tags: django

In a form I have a drop down of usernames, this is referenced in the 'taken_by' field. I would like to display first_name and last_name, this is achieved through the `__str__` but I can't seem to get it to function, the list of usernames are presented but not the firstname. Suggestions welcome.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    area_easting = models.IntegerField(choices = EASTING_CHOICES)
    area_northing = models.IntegerField(choices = NORTHING_CHOICES)
    context_number = models.IntegerField()
    sample_number = models.IntegerField()
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True, choices = MATERIALS)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    recovery_method = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True, choices = RECOVERY_METHODS)
    taken_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='taken_by', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.taken_by.first_name
        # return str(self.sample_id)
        # return str(self.firstname)+ '-' +str(self.lastname)
        # return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Form setup as requested

```
class BotanySampleFilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = (
        # 'botany_id',
        'sample_id',
        'area_easting',
        'area_northing',
        'context_number',
        'sample_number',
        'material_type',
        'weight',
        'description',
        'recovery_method',
        'taken_by',
        'comments'

        )
```

Comment: Can you add your form code?

Comment: if i got you right,  then you need to give that __str__ function in the User model and not the Sample model.

Comment: Form code added
I'm using the User model which is inside Django, from the database side I see the field names I need are `firstname` and `lastname` while `username` is currently displayed